# How to prevent JScrollPane grow by its JTextArea without make it fixed size?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, grouplayout

I'm trying to write an apartment management program with a TabbedPane, I created a class extending JPanel with GroupLayout and added it to my TabbedPane. I have two JTextAreas in this class and I put them in JScrollPanes.

When I write them anything long, their ScrollPanes are growing horizontally, how can I prevent it.

I tried to add `textarea.setLineWrap(true);` line, it solves my problem but it generates a new problem; I cannot resize them automatically my ScrollPanes. So they becomes in fixed size.

```
    JTextArea diger = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane digerS = new JScrollPane(diger);
    JTextArea rapor = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane raporS = new JScrollPane(rapor);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(5)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(kisiBilgileri)
                    .addComponent(daireBilgileri)
                    .addComponent(iletisimBilgileri)
                    .addComponent(_diger, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(digerS, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE) //textarea1's scrollpane
            )
            .addGap(5)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(ara, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(daireSec, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(kaydet, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(sil, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(_rapor, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(raporS, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE) //textarea2's scrollpane
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(aidatAy)
                            .addGap(5)
                            .addComponent(aidatEvDurumu)
                    )
                    .addComponent(aidatTuru)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(aidatMiktar)
                            .addGap(5)
                            .addComponent(aidatOde)
                    )
            )
            .addGap(5)
    );
```

and my program looks like:
[image: First and normal]

[image: Second and have problem]

Comment: We’ll need a [mre] so that we can reproduce this ourselves.  I’m not able to determine from the code you’ve shown us whether you’re adding JScrollPanes to your layout, or adding the JTextAreas directly.

Comment: *textfield.setLineWrap(true);* - why would you call a JTextArea a "textField"? That is very confusing since there is also a JTextField component. Use meaningful names to make your code readable. *I cannot resize them automatically my ScrollPanes* - not sure what that means.

Comment: @camickr Sorry, a typo :)

Comment: @VGR How is it now?

Comment: When you create a JTextArea you should use something like: `new JTextArea(5, 20)`, when the number "suggest" the default row/columns of the text area so it can determine its preferred size. The layout manager may override the suggestion, but at least it has a starting point. I've never used a GroupLayout so I have no ideas what all those constraints are.

Comment: @camickr trying...

Comment: @camickr Oh thanks, it works. You can write it answer, I'll mark it solution.

Comment: What do .addComponent(_diger,…) and .addComponent(_rapor,…) do?  Are those the same as the `diger` and `rapor` JTextArea declarations you added in your edit?  If they are, then you are adding both your JTextArea and the JScrollPane to your layout, which you should *not* do.  The JTextArea’s parent needs to be the JScrollPane, and you should add only the JScrollPane to your layout.

Comment: @VGR No, they are JLabels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTextArea diger = new JTextArea();
```

When you create a JTextArea like above the text area doesn't know how to size itself so it may change in size as text is added/removed (depending on the layout manager used, I don't know how GroupLayout works).

Instead you should use something like:

```
JTextArea diger = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

to suggest the number of row and columns for the text area. Now the text area can determine its own preferred size and the layout manager can use this information.

Note, the same applies for a JTextField, except you can only specify the columns.